# Mac problems when doing git merge master with branch that has bower

Tags: git, macos, merge, bower, git-checkout

Quite new to git and mac.

But I'm using the `Git Plus` in Atom to handle all my version control via git. But I'm having a lot problems if I add components/libs via bower to my ionic project.

Working on branch `quick_fix` and adding a `angular-cookies` (ionic stores it in a folder called `lib`). Update the code and do some commits.

Had some problems doing it in Atom after using `bower`, so try the terminal. So I do the following in the Terminal:

```
git checkout master

warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/.bower.json: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/LICENSE.md: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/README.md: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js.map: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/bower.json: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/index.js: Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink www/lib/angular-cookies/package.json: Permission denied
```

So these files are now still in the folder... even though that I'm back to the master code that doesn't have the hot fixes...

```
git status

On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    www/lib/angular-cookies/
```

If I try to do a merge I get the following

```
sudo git merge quick_fix

Updating 034f577..8b74fa5
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    www/lib/angular-cookies/.bower.json
    www/lib/angular-cookies/LICENSE.md
    www/lib/angular-cookies/README.md
    www/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js
    www/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js
    www/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js.map
    www/lib/angular-cookies/bower.json
    www/lib/angular-cookies/index.js
    www/lib/angular-cookies/package.json
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

How do I do a merge?

I think that the problem has to do with doing a checkout to master without doing `sudo`. So I'm not giving it permission to delete the folders.. Is there any way I can give permanent sudo permissions to delete files in this working directory - so the Atom editor can do a checkout to master without keeping the added component..

Problem is that I can't checkout `quick_fix` because it gives me the same error and aborts.

Comment: In the working directory: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ./www/lib` will bring you the right permission!

Comment: @dNitro after doing what you suggest I ran into the following problem https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-helper-wants-to-make-changes/17260

Comment: At least now we know that its not a *git* problem nor a *bower*'s one! It's all about peimission. And seems your Atom is not running with right permissions so every time you ask it for a change it examines your identity!

Comment: @dNitro how do I reverse it...?

Comment: Of course we does not do anything harmfull, by this command we just **ch**anged **own**ership for *lib* directory and all of the files and subdirectories contained within(**-R**) to **$(whoami)** variable. you can see the value of this var by doing `echo $(whoami)`.

Comment: To revert, in the working directory `ls -la www` to see a list of files and directories beside *lib* folder formatted like: *drwxr-xr-x    3 **User**  **group**    102 Jul 16 16:41 example*. Then run `sudo chown -R User:group ./www/lib` (replace *User* and *group* with user and group of files and folders beside your lib dir) to match your *lib* dir with other ones. BUT why revert, TRY to resolve.

Comment: thought a revert would resolve... I tried a lot and now it works.. Not completely sure what did the trick...

Comment: @dNitro I did a `sudo chown -R 777 ./www` that seem to do the trick.. not sure if that was to much access to grant

Comment: Great. Happy gitting :)

Answer (score 1):

> Had some problems doing it in Atom after using bower, so try the terminal.

That is a good idea, but you need to close Atom first, before the git checkout.
Otherwise, Atom would keep an handle on those files, which results in the error message you saw.

While in command-line, close as much other applications as possible in order to do the (clean) checkout you need.
You might [need a `git clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28082580/6309) before resuming your work on your checked out branch.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!