# Git migration doesn't work for removed files

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab-8

We have two Vendors working of the same piece of code. Due to logistics issue both maintain their own instances of git.

We sync the code periodically using the following approach:

1. git pull from vendor1
2. add a remote for vendor2
3. Push to vendor 2
4. Repeat this process

However, when a file is removed from vendor1 it should be removed for vendor2 as well. But somehow our process is failing to remove the files from vendor2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commit recording a file deletion should delete said file when the branch is pulled and merged in vendor2.

But when a vendor2 contributor update his/her own working tree locally, he/she might still have a copy of that file in the editor, and could save, add and commit again said file.

It is important to **[clean one own's working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/6309)** in order to remove any local file which might be obsolete.

```
git clean -f -d -x $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)
```