# Is there an easy way to delete untracked git files

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

From time to time I have untracked files in my git repository and I'd like to delete them.

Is there an easy way to do so using git or bash or even another way?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) command.

```
git clean -f -d # will delete all untracked directories and files.
```

Comment: duplicated question: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree?rq=1

Comment: That is still no reason for downvoting the answer. It's the job of OP to make sure that the question is not already asked.