# .gitignore not ignoring a file properly

Tags: git, unix, cmake, gitignore

I have a project and its structure is following:

```
build/
.git/
.gitignore
LICENSE
pics/
project.c
README.md
shared/
solutions/
```

My `build/` folder is where I use CMake so there are various files like `CMakeCache.txt`, `CMakeLists.txt` etc. which I want git to ignore.

My `.gitignore` file has:

```
.gitignore
*.out
*.swp
/build/*
```

When I run `git status` there is `modified: CMakeLists.txt` which I don't understand. Why is `CMakeLists.txt` not ignored? And why is it the only file that's not ignored?

Comment: What's the output of `git ls-files --error-unmatch build/CMakeLists.txt` command?

Comment: the output is `build/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `git ls-files --error-unmatch build/CMakeLists.txt` does not show you any error, it means that `build/CMakeLists.txt` file is already tracked in your repo, so `.gitignore` file does not affect it anymore. You need to run `git rm --cached build/CMakeLists.txt` to delete it from git.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore rules (like those in `.gitignore`) only apply to *untracked* files.  Changes to tracked files cannot be ignored.  There are mechanisms people like to suggest for this use case, but they all cause more trouble than the solve.

(And we know that the file in question is tracked, because git tells you it's *modified*.  That means there's a version of the file already in the index.)

If you remove the file from the index then ignore rules can apply.  That means that from this commit forward, the repo contains *no* version of the file.  If you want ignore to successfully cover the entire `build` directory, you could say

```
git rm -r --cached build
```

Of course if the file still exists in other "current" commits (i.e. on other branches), then it will still be there (and could sneak back into your current branch by way of merges).

If you never meant the file to be there and can abide a history rewrite, you might consider using BFG Repo Cleaner to fully get rid of it; but it is an extreme solution that will change commit ID's and require any collaborators to replace their repos.

As an aside, there is basically no reason to ever put `.gitignore` itself in the `.gitignore` file.  Normally you want ignore rules shared as part of the repo, but if you don't you can use `.git/info/exclude` instead of `.gitignore`.

You also don't need separate entries for path-based exclusion and extension-based exclusion, unless files with the given extension exist outside the given path.

Answer (score -1):

Add directory into `.gitignore`:

```
echo 'node_modules/' >> .gitignore
```

Add file into `.gitignore`:

```
echo 'config/constants.js' >> .gitignore
```

then:

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules/
```

or:

```
git rm -r --cached config/constants.js
```

Add your other files:

```
git add .
```

or:

```
git add --all
```

Commit it:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

Finally push your code into the repo.