# The equivalent option in git as option `--delete` in 'rsync'

Tags: git

command `rsync` has option `--delete` to delete extraneous files from dest dirs, like:

```
    rsync --delete /etc /home /usr/local
```

I have a repository cloned from github and perform the following operations daily

```
    git fetch upstream # not origin, it's upstream
    git merge upstream/master
```

After get my repository updated, I only work on one 'hello.md' file everyday

```
    git add 'hello.md'
    git add commit -m 'updated hello.md by hello on 2018-03-30'
```

Over time, my repository has multiple files that have already been deleted from the upstream.

Is there an option as `--delete` in `async` to remove files that may have existed on local repository but no longer existed on the upstream.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/3584153

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)