# Not able to remove untracked content in git

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove untracked directory ***git-blame-example*** . I've tried `git clean -df` but it's not removing. Just to check i've also tried `git clean -dfx` but got no solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git reset --hard
```

Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files
in the working tree since  are discarded.

```
git clean -f -d
```

Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. **In your case it looks like the untracked directory is managed by a different git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.**

**Also,  If you don't want to remove files that are in `.gitignore`, then do not provide the `-x` flag.**

## Description:

Git Tips: Remove untracked files and directories from the working
tree when switching branches or checking out different commits.

## Explanation:

When switching branches or checking out another set of commits,
you might want to only have the files and directories that are
a part of that actual version. The commands shown above will
accomplish this.

Be warned that any untracked files will be deleted, along with
changes to tracked files. The two commands together reset the
index and working tree, so ensure that any changes you don't want
to lose were either committed to another branch or otherwise
backed up somehow.

```
-f
--force
```

If the git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to run unless given -f or -n.

Answer (score 4):

It seems `git-blame-example` project is also another git project inside `git_test`.

You did not say what it says when you run command `git clean -df`. I tried to replicate in my system and it says

> Skipping repository git-blame-example/

So if you really want to delete it, then you have to add extra `f` in the option.

You have to use this command to delete it
`git clean -dff`

You can find more about this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/1610918).

Comment: Thanks very much. You saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

`git-blame-example` in your case is a "submodule".  To see its status:

```
cd git-blame-example
git status
```

Then you will see the untracked content in the submodule, which you can clean.

Comment: Yes, you're right. but can you tell me how can i delete this directory from git.  because i've also tried to remove this `git rm -rf git-blame-example`

Comment: How to remove a submodule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule