# cannot commit and push in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to push some file using git, but when I add some file which want to push and when I commit that, show this :

`git commit -m "Form-View-Controller-Models-Seeder-Route-Team"`

`On branch dev`

`Changes not staged for commit:`

```
    `modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`
    `modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php`
```

even though it's not my file who doesn't want to push. when I try `git status` show this :

`git status`

`On branch dev`

`Changes not staged for commit:`

`(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)`

`(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)`

```
    `modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`
    `modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php`
    `modified:   app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php`
```

[image]
[image]

is there any other way than move or remove ?
what should I do?

Comment: `git add` the files you want to commit, *then* do `git commit`

Comment: What files do you want to add to the commit?

Comment: @RPGillespie it has use `git add`

Comment: see in my question

Answer (score 1):

Running `git add` on a file that has not been modified does nothing. According to the screenshot you included, you're trying to stage a bunch of files that have not changed, so there's nothing to commit when you go and run `git commit`. If you looked at the bottom of your screenshot after the modified file listing, you'd see the text `no changes added to commit`.

If you've previously committed those changes and you're attempting to push these to a remote repository, you should use `git push` with the appropriate arguments.

You can also type `git status` to see the full list of staged and unstaged changes in your local repository.

Comment: but the file I want to push is a new file

Comment: If it is a new file that has not previously been committed and is not covered by `.gitignore`, then it should show up as an unstaged change. Can you confirm that it has not previously been committed?

Comment: I have previously added and committed the file

Comment: Your new screenshot is indicating that you've got locally modified files that would be overwritten if you did the `git pull`. As per the instructions, you should either revert those changes (using `git clean` for untracked files and `git reset --hard` for modified files) or you should stage and commit those modified files before pulling.

Answer (score 0):

If you had committed your previously modified files and don't want to push newly modified files. Then you need to use `git stash`. After `git stash` you can push your commits.

For more detail you can read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: Using `git stash` but when I pull, there something error. see my question, screen shot

Comment: You can use git clean to remove untracked files from working directories. For more details read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree