# Why am I getting "Untracked files" error upon running git reset --hard HEAD?

Tags: git, debugging, github

After running `git reset hard --HARD`, I ran `git pull` and got the following error:

```
User-MacBook-Air:appName User$ git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at d32cc09 initial test
Users-MacBook-Air:appName User$ git pull
Updating d32cc09..35ece16
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        public/appName/js/password-change.js
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Isn't `git reset hard --HARD` supposed to reset everything that I've done in my branch to the way it was before?  If that's the case, then why's it `Aborting` when trying to pull in new code?  I thought it would trigger bringing forth the changes automatically because everything has been reseted?

What can I do to get past this?

Comment: The file Git is mentioning here `../js/password-change.js` is not yet tracked by Git. A `reset --hard @` will NOT touch this file. To remove this you would have to call `git clean -n`(which will list you all the files it _would_ delete and then confirm by calling  `git clean -f`. This error happens because the commit you are about to pull already has this file and would replace it.

Comment: Refer below [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)

Answer (score 2):

What to do is exactly what Git is telling you to do: either commit `public/appName/js/password-change.js`, or move it out of the way.

> Isn't `git reset --hard HEAD` supposed to reset everything that I've done in my branch to the way it was before?

Not exactly.  Or rather, exactly that, but *just* that is not what you want and/or mean.

Git has, at all times, *three* "active" versions of each *tracked* file.  There's one copy of the file in the current commit, where it is frozen into whatever form it had when whoever made the commit, made it.  Here, it's also compressed and stored in a Git-only form, to take less (maybe much less) space.  There's a *second* copy in a place that Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*, depending on who / which part of Git is doing the calling.  The index copy is also in the Git-only form, but not quite frozen—more sort of slushy, ready-to-freeze.  Finally, the third copy is the one you can use and see: the one in your work-tree, which has its normal form and hence you can work on / with it.

What `git reset --hard` does is to re-set all three copies of each of these three files, so that they all match the one in the current (`HEAD`) commit.  Well, it *can* do even more, but in this case that's what it does.  But that doesn't address something important.

If some files are *tracked*, that implies that other files are *untracked*.  And that's what Git is complaining about here: an *untracked file*.  So: what exactly does this mean?  What exactly is a tracked file anyway?

A *tracked file* is a file that is, right now, in the index.  That's it—it's really that simple.  A file that was in the commit you checked out, got into the index *from* that commit, and is probably still there.  So the file that was in the commit, is in the index and work-tree.  Using `git reset --hard` will re-set the index and work-tree copies.

An *untracked file*, by contrast, is one that is *not in the index*.  (It has to be in your work-tree, otherwise it's just non-existent all around.  If it's in the commit, `git reset --hard` will bring it back to both index and work-tree.)

Anyway, if it's not in the index right now, then either *you* removed it from the index, or it was never there in the first place.  The latter tends to be more common, since usually you remove files from the index using `git rm file`, which removes it from both the index and the work-tree.  And, we can be sure it's not in your `HEAD` commit, because if it were, `git reset --hard` would have brought it back into your index (and overwritten the work-tree copy with the committed copy).

So you have a file that you—or someone or something—created in the work-tree, that is for sure *not* in the index, nor in the current commit.  And now, by running `git pull`, you told Git to run `git merge`.  (Note that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`*.  The output you show indicates that you're getting not only `git merge` but specifically a *fast-forward* merge, which isn't really a merge at all, but has a lot of similarities.)

Merge has to take your current work, whatever that is, and merge it with someone else's work, whoever that someone else is.  To do that, Git has to find out what they did, and combine it with what you did.  While we can't see exactly what they did from what you've posted, what they did includes *adding a new file*.

**The new file they added is the one that you have as untracked.**  That is, you have:

```
public/appName/js/password-change.js
```

which is untracked—not in your index.  *They* committee a version of that file.  Git has no frozen copy of *your* version of this file to keep it safe.  Using `git merge` would simply *overwrite* your copy of `public/appName/js/password-change.js` with theirs.  So `git merge` tells you that this file is in the way: you should commit it, so that you have a frozen copy that keeps it safe, or move it out of the way, so that `git merge` can write *their* copy into place.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) The command is `git reset --hard HEAD`

2) Even so, if a file is untracked, git will not by default delete it during a hard reset (or most other operations).  It wants to make sure it only does this if you *explicitly* tell it to, because if it does, then because the file was untracked, you will have no way to recover it.

If you do know for certain that you mean to delete the local untracked files, you can use `git clean`.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean