# How to git reset all new files

Tags: git

I am to lazy to `git add`/`git reset` files one by one. And I don't know how to do this.
Tried `git add -A` (found on the internet). But It have added all "new files" to the index.
How to revert it back, keeping modified files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)

Answer (score -1):

`git add .` will add a whole current directory with all files and subfolders

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, in it's current form.