# How to remove all local files that were accidentally added to the git system

Tags: git

I'm new to the "git" system. I may have made a mistake and integrated all my local files into the "git" system.

I use "vs code editor" and discard all changes when I say gives me the following error: `Git: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born`.

this is what it looks like when I use the "git status" command in the terminal:

```
warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..."
    to include in what will be committed)
  .. / .npm /
  .. / .viminfo
  .. / .vscode /
  .. / .zsh_history
  .. / Applications /
  . /
  .. / Documents /
  .. / Downloads /
  .. / Library /
  .. / Movies /
  .. / Music /
  .. / Pictures /
  .. / Public /

  nothing added to commit but untracked files present(use "git add"
    to track)
```

Please don't think I came here looking for a solution. I tried pretty hard. I even read the articles here carefully.[How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61212/12348877).

`git clean`, `git reset` commands, such as I tried but failed. I'm trying to find out what I'm missing. I don't want to use the wrong command and ruin everything. If you can explain while you're helping, I'll know and I'll be happy. Thank you.

Comment: You mean you `git init` in directory `~/`?

Comment: I don't understand you. I'm sorry.

Comment: How did you add your files to git?

Comment: yeah, I think I did it by saying Git init. This may have happened because I messed up the folder locations when I was trying to git add on a new folder.

Comment: In which direcotry did you run `git status`? `/Users/<username>`?

Comment: I guess you `git init` in `/User/<username>` and that will generate a folder named **.git** in the current directory which tracks your files and folders. Simply delete the .git folder and you are good to go.

Comment: the problem is, every time I open a new folder, I get the same problem.

Comment: You are not listening. Look, do this. In the Finder, press Command Shift Period. Go into your home folder. See the _.git_ folder there? Trash it. — And do not futz with commands you do not understand. In the situation you are in, saying `git clean` can delete most of your hard drive.

Comment: @matt I think I've already deleted it with `clean` command.  Maybe it wasn't a big deal, but is there any way I can get it back ?

Comment: Deleted what? Get what back?

Comment: all my folders that are on my desktop and connected to git are empty.

Comment: Yep, well, I'm glad if that's all that happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `git init`, you are doing two things:

- You create a (normally invisible) *.git* folder in the current directory.
- You place the current directory and all its subdirectories recursively under git control.

So, if you whip out the Terminal and say

```
% git init
```

...the current directory is your home folder, and that is where the *.git* folder is created, and now your home folder and all its contents at any depth have been placed under git control. Which is a really bad idea, putting your whole world under git control.

Okay, so then you say

```
% cd Desktop
% git status
```

Well, the Desktop folder is inside the home folder, and the home folder has the *.git* folder, so the Desktop folder is under git control, and the `git status` command works, and correctly reports, "Hey, I'm supposed to be controlling all these files and folders. What would you like me to do?"

What you'd like it to do is *nothing*. You've made a silly mistake and you need to back it out. To do that, just delete the invisible *.git* folder you created earlier by mistake in your home directory. Done. Your world is no longer under git control.

(The easiest way to do that, in a modern Mac system, is to press Command-Shift-Period, which makes invisible folders visible, so you can see the *.git* folder and drag it into the trash.)

Now, if you also said `git clean` while your world was under git control, you may have deleted some of your stuff. And when I say deleted, I mean deleted. That stuff is absolutely irrevocably gone. If you use Time Machine or Carbon Copy Cloner or similar, you might have a backup elsewhere, but that has nothing to do with git. You told git to delete things and it obeyed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Really, really thank you.  I don't understand why other people would unvote the question. It's a beautifully explained question. It shouldn't have been a problem if I didn't understand.Anyway, that's a good lesson for me. Now I've decided to learn the "git" system in detail. Thanks again.