# How do I solve a history list of untracked files before making git commits for a current project?

Tags: git, macos, terminal, commit

I want to add 2 text files to a {master} project but I keep getting a list of untracked files that have nothing to do with my current project. Why is this happening and how can I solve it? MacOS v10.15.7 Catalina Terminal

**Added 1st text file:**

```
git add file1.txt
```

**Added 2nd text file:**

```
git add file2.txt
```

**Viewing working directory and staged files:**

```
git status
```

**Changes to be committed:**

```
new file: file1.txt

new file: file2.txt
```

**PLUS Keep getting a list of Untracked Files:**

```
    .Trash/
    .anaconda/
    .config/
    .idlerc/
    .ipython/
    .local/
    .matplotlib/
    .npm/
    .spyder-py3/
    .vscode/
    Applications/
    Creative Cloud Files/
    Desktop/
    Documents/
    Downloads/
    Library/
    Moon/
    Movies/
    Music/
    Pictures/
    Public/
    helloworld/
    opt/
```

**I deleted pronto!**

```
rm -rf ~/.git
```

**Checked**

```
git status
```

**Output**

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

**I'll start my project all over again, more aware!**

Comment: you need to perform a `git init` in the new directory where you plan to create the project like I mentioned below.  That's why you're getting the fatal error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all local files that were accidentally added to the git system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244042/how-to-remove-all-local-files-that-were-accidentally-added-to-the-git-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you initialized git in your home directory.  You probably want to initialize it in the project directory of the software you are creating.  Each project should have its own git repo.  You can remove the git repo from your home folder by moving it to another directory or deleting it entirely using `rm -Rf ~/.git` (note: this is not undoable!)  Once you have done that, cd into the folder/project you want to track and do another `git init`:

```
cd <some project folder>
git init
git add file1.txt
```

If you meant to put your entire home directory into git (which I don't recommend), you'll have to either put all the directories and files you don't want to track into the `.gitignore` file or just manually add the two files using `git add file1.txt`.  Git tracks any files in its directory unless they are explicitly put into gitignore.

Comment: I think this explains why my computer shut off suddenly. frig.