# VScode adding .Trash to Git Control?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

The git control in VScode whenever I create new folders and files has my entire `.Trash` folder on Mac. I try to `.gitignore` it, yet it's still there. In Github Desktop, the .Trash folder does not show. Why does this happen in VScode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all local files that were accidentally added to the git system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244042/how-to-remove-all-local-files-that-were-accidentally-added-to-the-git-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the Trash folder is usually under `$HOME` (`~/.Trash`), that would means your `$HOME` itself is tracked by Git: check if you have a `~/.git` subfolder.

That would explain why VSCode interpret that tree structure as a Git repo, including one of its subolders (`.Trash`)

Ideally, you would not need a repository directly in `$HOME`, but only in the parent folder of your project.