# Getting Back Deleted Files from VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I wanted to link my code to a Git repository that I had created, and while I was trying to do that in the Source Control section of the VS Code, it said that I had 10k files under the changes section and I wasn't able to push my code to my repository. When I said "discard changes" thinking it would turn back to normal, VS Code deleted all my local files on my MacBook and now I'm not able to find them. I don't understand how an IDE was able to delete my local files permanently from my device, but I really do need them back. And no I don't have a back up. It didn't just delete my code files, it also deleted some of PDFs and folders so I really don't know how to get them back. Please help me, I have lost a month's worth of stuff.

I was able to get my most recent code files from the Local History section, but my folders and Pdfs are nowhere to be found. I have tried cmd/ctrl + Z but it doesn't work since I had closed the window. Is it possible to get them back without using a file recovery software.

Comment: Sounds like the "classic" nightmare git clean scenario. One mistakenly sets a repo too high in the file system, somewhere near the root, with many many folders and files inside. Uses `git clean` (either in command line while trying to follow some commands found online, or through some misunderstood IDE menu option) without having commited anything yet. Everything's gone. Your "*And no I don't have a back up.*" sounds like bad news, I'm sorry. Like every powerful tool, git is dangerous without the required basic knowledge.

Comment: you should have done a search for `git 10k VSC`. How likely is it that you have 10k+ modified files in your project, so first find the cause of the error before you take any action. If you don't have an undelete util you are out of luck

Comment: See also (in addition to the duplicates cited at the top of this page) https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660769/341994

Comment: This is tragic! 
Have you checked Trash !? or `git stash list` ?

Comment: @YashashriPawar Files deleted by git don't go in any trash, they're deleted on the spot. And there's no stash in the described situation, unless VS Code does a stash under the hood to discard changes? Seems unlikely.

Comment: @Romain Valeri. ok, understood!