# Why do i see this untracked folder in Git?

Tags: git

[those folder exist in my computer but how did the get into git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDUfE.png)

I tried to delete them by typing command  *git clean -fd*
but i couldn't to be specify git didn't let me delete the folder.
I tried to delete them one by one and that also didn't work

Comment: It looks like you ran `git init` on your user home dir, and are working in that, rather than initializing your actual project dir, and working _there_.

Comment: `those folder exist in my computer but how did the get into git` They did not _get into git_. They are untracked.

Comment: Be very careful. You are in a very bad situation and must fix it immediately. If you were to say `git clean` you could end up deleting your whole hard drive. Find the invisible .git folder in this directory and delete it right now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244042/how-to-remove-all-local-files-that-were-accidentally-added-to-the-git-system

Comment: Run this command `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the exact path where the repo has been defined and delete the `.git` folder that is inside.