# I'm Using ASP .NET core with git repository command is not working

Tags: git

As you can see Git command to check status untrack file in my repository.
git status
[image]

i want to remove/ reset those untrack file but git command is not working
[image]

even i try clean untrack file still hard luck
[image]

even i try to pull from remote repository still no luck.

can anyone tell me how to remove those file from untrack status?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/7977581) should resolve all your queries.

> Step 1 is to show what will be deleted by using the -n option:
>
> ```
> # Print out the list of files and directories which will be removed (dry run)
> git clean -n -d
> ```
>
> Step 2 Clean Step - beware: this will delete files:
>
> ```
> # Delete the files from the repository
> git clean -f
> ```
>
> - To remove directories, run git clean -f -d or git clean -fd
> - To remove ignored files, run git clean -f -X or git clean -fX
> - To remove ignored and non-ignored files, run git clean -f -x or git clean -fx
>
> Note the case difference on the X for the two latter commands.
>
> If clean.requireForce is set to "true" (the default) in your
> configuration, one needs to specify -f otherwise nothing will actually
> happen.
>
> Again see the [git-clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) docs for more information.

`git clean -n` doesn't actually remove the files, but actually shows which files are going to be removed.

`git clean -f` removes and deletes the files from the repository.

Comment: No not working this command too

Comment: Since you are trying to remove a directory, use `git clean -fd`