# How can I remove patch files from my Git repository?

Tags: git

I'm just learning how to use Git, and somehow by mistake I've patched files and couldn't figure out how to remove them.

When I type `$ git status` it shows me the patched files which I don't want.

I've tried using `$ git apply -R <patch>` and it still won't work.

This is what appears when I type `$ git status` :

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree

Comment: Note that these files are *not in Git*. They are not in your *repository* at all; they are in your *working tree*.  Note also that the `.rej` files contain parts of the patch that failed: pay close attention to what did not make it in!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named '.gitignore' in the same directory as .git is.
Type in -

```
*.patch  
*.patch.orig   
*.patch.rej
```

as the content of the file.
When you run
`$ git status`
again, you will not see them any more.