# how to remove git repository form a folder already used for a project?

Tags: git

Mistakenly add a folder to my repository which was for another project , now I want to remove that folder which I mistakenly added to my repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree)

Comment: You added a folder to an existing repo and already push it?