# removing untracked change from git

Tags: git, terminal, git-checkout

I would appreciate if you help me in this problem I have with git. I am new with working with that. I need to remove untracked change from git. I have already tried "git checkout ." and " git restore .", but those are not working always. Is there any more reliable way? Any help is appreciated.

This is the untracked file I need to be removed from git:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        secret1.txt

 test-repo % git restore .
 test-repo % git status
HEAD detached from V2
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        secret1.txt

 test-repo % git checkout .
Updated 0 paths from the index
 test-repo % git status
HEAD detached from V2
Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        secret1.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

As you can see secret1.txt is still there!

Comment: First link in the related bar to the right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"untracked changes" are by definition files which git knows nothing about. The easiest way to fix this is just to delete the file with `rm secret1.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Git commands:

- `git clean -f` (remove all untracked files)
- `git clean -f path/to/file` (remove the specific file path/to/file)