# Cannot delete folders with git clean -f (Windows 11)

Tags: windows, git

I have a 'Test' folder for trying out things using git which looks like this

```bash
source
├── src.txt
├── src
│   ├── asdfasdfadsfasdf.txt
│   ├── src-src.txt.txt
```

i used git clean -f within the folder using Powershell, and it said that "Deletion of directory 'source/src
' failed. Should i try again? (y/n)"

I put in 'n' then 'y', then deleted all files within the src directory but not the folders. See screenshot for details/proof.

[image]

May I ask why this is the case? How can I fix this?

For additional info, I am using my personal laptop and so I am the only user and admin.

Edit:

I tried running `git clean -f -d` and it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/7976758 `git clean -f -d` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clean+directory

Comment: There is a `-d` option to delete empty directories. See 2nd answer in question suggested by phd:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/912737/86072

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working though, I edited the question to reflect your suggestions