Jenkins with git: How to clean up workspace except files in gitignore
In jenkins freestyle project, I use git and add clean up before build behavior. But I just want to clean files that are not in gitignore. How can I do this?
And it's great if I can turn on or off this ignoring option for clean build.

Expected:

Don't clean up files in gitignore
Turn on off this option


What I did:

Create new freestyle project

Add git plugin in Jenkins: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/

Add clean before build advanced behavior in git plugin Jenkins



Result: clean up all files including files in gitignore; can't turn on off this option


https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/7976758 git clean -f -d cleans all but preserves ignored files; git clean -f -d -X cleans all including ignored files. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clean+gitignore

[Edited Post] I used freestyle project so I don't know if there are any methods to insert a step before check out
